# How to check which tablespaces is user granted in DB2 v9 z/os?

Tags: db2, mainframe

On DB2 for linux platform I can check it in the `SYSIBM.SYSTBSPACEAUTH` table. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSTBSPACEAUTH WHERE GRANTEE=....
```

How can this be done on z/os since there is no `SYSIBM.SYSTBSPACEAUTH` table?

Thanks in advance,
GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be SYSIBM.SYSRESAUTH table I think.

```
select 
  name 
from 
  sysibm.sysresauth
where
  grantee = ? and 
  obtype  = 'R'                   -- tablespace
```